# How can I make APNS work for IBM i (iSeries)?

Tags: apache, apple-push-notifications, ibm-midrange

My company would like me to implement push notifications for an app that is in development. These notifications would be based off of events occurring on our Iseries (AS/400 ).

I have utilized IBM Web Administration for I to create a HTTP Server and have used Digital Certificate Manager to attach APNS certificates to said server.

I am also storing device tokens in a database on our AS400.

I am now having a hard time figuring out how to go about creating this 'persistent connection' to APNS with the server I created. I have little to no knowledge of server side programming and any help or direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I've been trying to research different things but I'm still unsure how to start. I am assuming that I need to do some kind of server side programming but I cannot see any examples for this with IBM HTTP server powered by Apache

Answer (score 0):

I found examples like [this one using PHP](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).  IBM i will run Zend Server, which will give you PHP.

Comment: Thank you I will keep this in mind. Right now I found a tutorial in creating sockets that I am trying to implement.